# How to match the 2nd occurence of a string with regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a URL like this

```
http://www.abc.com/h/x/y
```

and I want to parse "x/y" from it using a regex.  I am using following regex

```
h/(?<Group>[\s\S]*?)\s*?/
```

But it only matches "x" but I want "x/y". I can find the 2nd occurence of '/' using a programming language and then parse it but I want to do it from regex only.

Please help.

Comment: Sidenote: don't you think that taking a substring might be more readable and easier than a regex?

Comment: Can you specify what you are trying to get from Url? What if URL will look like `http://www.abc.com/h/x/y/z`? And why only regex?

Answer (score 0):

I would not use regex, but simply:

```
var url = "http://www.abc.com/h/x/y";
var ix1 = url.LastIndexOf('/');
var ix2 = url.LastIndexOf('/', ix1 - 1);
var part = url.Substring(ix2 + 1);
```

This one is understandable without the need of explaining a complex regular expression :)

(+ validating whether it's a valid url can be done separately before the actual parsing)

Comment: And what happens if you've got a changing number of slashes? Also your return value will be wrong if `x` is longer than one character.

Comment: Where did you see this possibility in the requirement?

Comment: I'd just assume that from common sense (given the fact with one character your possibilities for the number of possible URLs are rather limited).

Comment: @L-Three actually requirements are poor, and OP do not answer the questions. I like substrings more, than regex in this case, but I can't consider this as answer while requirements are not clear.

Comment: So basically this solution assumes that `x` is one char while `y` can be more than one? Why this special treatment? You could assume `y` is a single char too and write `Substring(url, url.Length -3)`...

Answer (score 0):

The final regular expression will most like depend on the valid URLs you'd like to parse, e.g. is `h` constant or can it change as well?

I'd probably use something like this:

```
http://(?:[a-z\d\-]+\.)*[a-z\d]+/h/(.*)
```

- The first part (`http://`) matching the protocol is rather obvious.
- The non-capturing group (`(?:[a-z\d\-]+\.)*`) with the `*` quantifier will match all (sub) domains under the TLD including the last `.` (if any). If a IP is given, this will contain the first part of the IP.
- `[a-z\d]+` will match the TLD or - for intranet stuff - the domain name (like `localhost`). In case an IP is given, this will contain the last byte.
- The actual capture Group (`(.*)`) will simply capture anything following the `/h/`.

This implementation has two downsides:

- In its current state, IPv6 IPs aren't supported. Nor are given port numbers or other protocols. These would require minimal adjustments I'm sure you can figure out on your own.
- This will still parse invalid URLs, such as `http://--some-weird.--.com/h/1/2/3`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a much simpler solution.
Please make string.Length validation check, this is a quick mockup.

```
    string myString = @"http://www.microsoft.com/products/surface/order/pay.aspx";
    char charToFind = '/';
    int nthOccuranceToFind = 4;
    int startIndex = -1;
    int nthPosOfCharToFind = 0;

    while (nthOccuranceToFind > 0)
    {
        int findIndex = startIndex + 1;
        startIndex = myString.IndexOf(charToFind, findIndex);
        --nthOccuranceToFind;
    }

    //startIndex here will contain index of nth occurance.
```

Comment: How do you define simpler?