# How to split a string on the nth occurrence?

Tags: c#

What I want to do is to split on the nth occurrence of a string (in this case it's "\t"). This is the code I'm currently using and it splits on every occurrence of "\t".

```
string[] items = input.Split(new char[] {'\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

If input = "one\ttwo\tthree\tfour", my code returns the array of:

- one
- two
- three
- four

But let's say I want to split it on every "\t" after the second "\t". So, it should return:

- one    two
- three
- four

Comment: `\t` isn't a newline; it's a tab. Did you mean to say `newline`?

Comment: your question is not clear edit it

Comment: Oh, right. I meant tab then. But that doesn't matter. It should be the same method to split any string on the nth occurrence and how do I do that?

Comment: If the performance is not the issue, then after splitting, merge n-1 first items into one string and all items from nth to the end to the second string.

Comment: Find index of nth occurance then do a substring http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829739/how-to-match-the-2nd-occurence-of-a-string-with-regex/15830435#15830435

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is nothing built in.

You can use the existing `Split`, use `Take` and `Skip` with `string.Join` to rebuild the parts that you originally had.

```
string[] items = input.Split(new char[] {'\t'}, 
                             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string firstPart = string.Join("\t", items.Take(nthOccurrence));
string secondPart = string.Join("\t", items.Skip(nthOccurrence))

string[] everythingSplitAfterNthOccurence = items.Skip(nthOccurrence).ToArray();
```

---

An alternative is to iterate over all the characters in the string, find the index of the nth occurrence and substring before and after it (or find the next index after the nth, substring on that etc... etc... etc...).

Comment: This is much better than mine. I was unaware of the `Take` and `Skip` options. Great answer...

Comment: The OP edited his question, so it seems he wants to split on every occurrence *after* the nth, so the requirement has changed.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - Well, easy enough. The `Skip` will do it.

Comment: I'm getting an error at the last line of your code. 
    "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)". I'm new to this stuff. :/

Comment: @RayOzel - Added a `ToArray()` to the last statement.

Answer (score 4):

[EDIT] After re-reading the edited OP, I realise this doesn't do what is now asked. This will split on every nth target; the OP wants to split on *every* target AFTER the nth one.

I'll leave this here for posterity anyway.

---

If you were using the [MoreLinq extensions](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) you could take advantage of its `Batch` method.

Your code would then look like this:

```
string text = "1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7\t8\t9\t10\t11\t12\t13\t14\t15\t16\t17";

var splits = text.Split('\t').Batch(5);

foreach (var split in splits)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", split));
```

I'd probably just use Oded's implementation, but I thought I'd post this for an alternative approach.

The implementation of `Batch()` looks like this:

```
public static class EnumerableExt
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> Batch<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int size)
    {
        TSource[] bucket = null;
        var count = 0;

        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (bucket == null)
                bucket = new TSource[size];

            bucket[count++] = item;

            if (count != size)
                continue;

            yield return bucket;

            bucket = null;
            count = 0;
        }

        if (bucket != null && count > 0)
            yield return bucket.Take(count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you will have to split and re-combine. Something like

```
int tabIndexToRemove = 3;
string str = "My\tstring\twith\tloads\tof\ttabs";
string[] strArr = str.Split('\t');
int numOfTabs = strArr.Length - 1;
if (tabIndexToRemove > numOfTabs)
    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
str = String.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < strArr.Length; i++)
    str += i == tabIndexToRemove - 1 ? 
        strArr[i] : String.Format("{0}\t", strArr[i]);
```

Result:

> My  string  withloads  of  tabs

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Return a substring of str upto but not including
// the nth occurence of substr
function getNth(str, substr, n) {
  var idx;
  var i = 0;
  var newstr = '';
  do {
    idx = s.indexOf(c);
    newstr += str.substring(0, idx);
    str = str.substring(idx+1);
  } while (++i < n && (newstr += substr))
  return newstr;
}
```