C# how to remove the rest of a string after specific character
How do I remove everything in this string after the second - (not the first one)?
P037315F1-FB12-40-Fully Threaded MSB HOT DIP GALVANIZED   

I need the result to be
P037315F1-FB12


Somewhat equal just for splitting and no truncating. But the ideas are applicable here also. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034792/how-to-split-a-string-on-the-nth-occurrence

string result = string.Join('-', source.Split('-', 3).Take(2)); or string result = source.Substring(0, source.IndexOf('-', source.IndexOf('-') + 1));

What should happen if there aren't at least two dashes?

Your result suggests that you are removing the stuff after (and including) the 3rd "-", not the 2nd one.

I have adapted my answer to meet your new requirements.

Try a Regular expression like: (.*?-.*?)-.*
Test it at regex101.
Examples on how to use regex with C# can be found here.
Example Code C#:
string input = @"P037315F1-FB12-40-Fully Threaded MSB HOT DIP GALVANIZED";
string pattern = @"(.*?-.*?)-.*";
string output = Regex.Split(input, pattern)[1];
Console.WriteLine(output); //P037315F1-FB12

Make sure to add using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
Edit:
Question changed: New targeted string is now P037315F1-FB12 instead of P037315F1-FB12-40

FYI you can share links to regex101 by clicking "save new regex" at top left eg. your screenshot could be linked as https://regex101.com/r/Pq3UgJ/1

Thanks mate, I updated my answer now including the saved regex.

string input = "P037315F1-FB12-40-Fully Threaded MSB HOT DIP GALVANIZED";

// Find the index of the second occurrence of "-"
int firstDashIndex = input.IndexOf('-');
int secondDashIndex = input.IndexOf('-', firstDashIndex + 1);

// Find the index of the third occurrence of "-"
int thirdDashIndex = input.IndexOf('-', secondDashIndex + 1);

// If the third dash exists, take a substring up to that index (excluding the third "-")
string result = thirdDashIndex != -1 ? input.Substring(0, thirdDashIndex) : input;

Console.WriteLine(result); // Output: P037315F1-FB12-40


You can iterate through the string and find the location of the third dash so that you can only include the part of the string that occurs before the third dash.
int counter = 0; // initialize a counter variable
int dashIndex = 0; // keep track of the index of the third dash
string example = "testing-1-2-3"; // your string
    
for(int i = 0; i < example.Length; i++){
  if(example[i] == '-'){
     counter++; // increments counter each time a dash is found
  }

  if(counter == 3){
    dashIndex = i; // saves current index
    break; // exits loop
  }
}

Console.WriteLine(example.Substring(0, dashIndex)); // the portion of the string you want

